# Divide list into sublists with specific sizes

Tags: prolog

I need to divide list in that way: first and last sublists contain 1 element, second and second last contain 2 elements and so on.. I wrote a simplier version of that predicate: I just put 1 element in first sublists, 2 in second and so on. How to write predicate that I need?

Below I put my code:

```
divide(List, ListOfParts):-
  divide(List, 1, ListOfParts).
  
divide(List, N, [List]):-
  length(List, Len), Len =< N, !.

divide(List, N, [FirstN|TailParts]):-
  append(FirstN, Tail, List),
  length(FirstN, N), !, 
  NextN is N+1,
  divide(Tail, NextN, TailParts).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
segment_list(Lst, LstSegments) :-
    length(Lst, LenLst),
    segment_list_(Lst, LenLst, 1, LstSegments).

segment_list_(Lst, LenLst, LenSegment, LstSegments) :-
    % Using compare, to prevent unwanted choicepoint
    compare(Comp, LenLst, 0),
    segment_list_comp_(Comp, Lst, LenLst, LenSegment, LstSegments).

% Have reached end, if "middle" is empty
segment_list_comp_(=, [], 0, _, []).

segment_list_comp_(>, Lst, LenLst, LenSegment, LstSegments) :-
    LenMiddle is LenLst - (LenSegment * 2),
    LenMiddle >= 0,
    % Set length of LstMiddle, to avoid choicepoint in append/2
    length(LstMiddle, LenMiddle),
    % Segment lengths
    length(LstStart, LenSegment),
    length(LstEnd, LenSegment),
    % Segment contents - to make e.g. [1, 3, 4, 2] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]
    append([LstStart, LstEnd, LstMiddle], Lst),
    LenSegment1 is LenSegment + 1,
    segment_list_(LstMiddle, LenMiddle, LenSegment1, LstSegmentsMiddle),
    % Append after recursion, so LstSegmentsMiddle is nonvar, to prevent infinite loop
    append([[LstStart], LstSegmentsMiddle, [LstEnd]], LstSegments).
```

(Am using swi-prolog.)

This is deterministic:

```
?- time(segment_list([a, b, c, d, e, f], LstSeg)).
% 94 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 944088 Lips)
LstSeg = [[a],[c,d],[e,f],[b]].

?- time(segment_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], LstSeg)).
% 94 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 932216 Lips)
LstSeg = [[1],[3,4],[5,6],[2]].
```

... and general:

```
?- segment_list(LstRaw, LstSeg), length(LstRaw, LstRawLen).
LstRaw = LstSeg, LstSeg = [],
LstRawLen = 0 ;
LstRaw = [_A,_B],
LstSeg = [[_A],[_B]],
LstRawLen = 2 ;
LstRaw = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F],
LstSeg = [[_A],[_C,_D],[_E,_F],[_B]],
LstRawLen = 6 ;
LstRaw = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L],
LstSeg = [[_A],[_C,_D],[_G,_H,_I],[_J,_K,_L],[_E,_F],[_B]],
LstRawLen = 12 ;
```

Comment: can I ask you to write a short(or long) explanation of predicates?

Comment: Which bits require explanation?

Comment: seems to me I understand all.
how to make predicate work like that?
[1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [[1],[3,4],[5,6],[2]]
I mean we should move through start list, take first element and add to first sublist, take second element and add to last, then take two elements and add to second, take two elements and put to second last and so on...

Comment: Updated, to make [[1],[3,4],[5,6],[2]].